# Displaying all results from Query horizontally

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm writing a program to attempt speeding up the sign-in time for training classes. The design I have devised for the program is that each button is tied to a certain class time, and only the names tied to that class time will show up. I managed to successfully get the program to run the query for the first time slot, but I seem to only get the first result, and it displays it in vertical form. I'm trying to figure out how to obtain all the entries from the query, and have them display horizontally in a checkbox list. I have been sifting through MSDN, googling "displaying SQL results in VB" and I've looked at several questions which have been posted here, I don't know if I have over-looked something. At the moment I have been working on only one class time. I'm still digging around posted questions.
Any ideas on what I might be missing, or ways with which I can enhance the code a little bit? 
Update: i updated the code, since it provided the desired output. i will continue to work on improving the code per the suggestions given.

Comment: What are all entries. Is that all times and users? Are you only getting one record back?

Comment: What is the problem with your code? What's the result you get and what is the expected result?

Comment: Tip: don't do this `'Declare command ..  Dim compcmand As SqlCommand` this is waste of space and noise. When I look at code, I see that you "declare command". Comments should only explain "why" you do something for the

Comment: If I am understanding what you asked correctly, no this is not all the times and users, so far i have only been working with the first class time. in Sql when i run the query it shows me the 37 entries for that time slot. Visual basic just keep sptting back the first entry to me repeatedly.

Comment: A problem here ? -> `'Monday, March 7 - 4:00 - '` comparing date to string

Comment: julien, the code is returning only the first result for the query. the expected result is a handful of names tied to a specific class time.

Comment: T.S - that is the time for the class as listed in the Database. when i run the query along those lines in SQL it gives me all the names tied to that class time

Comment: It looks like you are displaying your results in a list box when you should be using a data grid.  `row = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)` is only going to get results from the first row of the table of results.  You need to loop through the rows to get data from all of them, or use the results to fill a DataGrid.  If you need to use the checked list box, then you probably need to concatenate the results into one line instead of adding them individually.

Comment: You probably also want to check out [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlphp/2008/09/30/how-and-why-to-use-parameterized-queries/) for information on Parameterized Queries.

Comment: Kateract, thank you for the parameterized query article and I am looking into a DataGrid now.

Comment: Couple of things. You don't need all the comments as already mentioned. Instead of `Dim CompCon As SqlConnection` at the top and then later on `CompCon = New SqlConnection...` you could just do `Using con as New SqlConnection("Data Source...)`. The same with your `SqlCommand`. (Using will dispose of your objects so you don't have to) I'd also do away with the `SqlDataAdapter` and look at using a `DataTable`. Fill it like so `DataTable.Load(compcmand.ExecuteReader)` (Unless you are looking at doing updates etc then ignore me). And use parameters.

Comment: sorry for the delay in responding, i was editing code. So, i shouldn't use a dataset, but a data table instead? or am i using the two hand in hand?

Comment: A DataSet holds a collection of DataTables. That's all. You can use a DataSet but feel it's not necessary here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be confused as to what you're asking, but I think what you want is:

```
Dim myString As String    

For Each row As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
    myString = row("FirstName").ToString() & " "
    myString &= row("LastName").ToString()  & " "
    myString &= row("CompanyName").ToString()  & " "
    myString &= row("classtime").ToString()  & " "
    myString &= row("BoothNumber").ToString()
    ClassAttendance.Items.Add(myString)
Next
```

This will let you get the value of each of those columns for each row in ds.Tables(0)'s Rows collection.

Comment: the error that i receive from this is an overload, due to no add accepting this many arguments

Comment: Apologies, I think I understood a bit better on this last edit what you need.

Comment: No need to apologize. quite the opposite. i appreciate the assistance. the revision you provided gave me the output that i was looking for.

Comment: I will say, for the most part I agree with Kateract's suggestion of using a data grid. Long-term it's much easier to deal with your data. The only addition I'd make to what they said was that I've had good luck adding a column of checked boxes to my DataGridViews, so you could still use the check box if you need it, you'd just have to look into how to loop through the DataGridView. Food for thought next time you have something similar.

Comment: I like the answer  user7426900